# Spring не запускает index.html

Tags: java, spring

Столкнулся с проблемой.Это абсолютно новый проект. Весь код - это лишь запуск приложения в main. Я пытаюсь задать index.html, как home page. В документации было сказано, что достаточно поместить данный файл в src/main/resourses/static (или public). Но у меня данная страница не отображается. В чём может быть причина
[image: Структура Проекта]
[image: Результат работы]

```
plugins {
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'
id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
id 'java'}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

configurations {
  developmentOnly
    runtimeClasspath {
      extendsFrom developmentOnly}}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
  testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
    exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
 }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Покажи все файлы, ибо не совсем понятно, где ошибка. Для кода есть отдельное форматирование.

Comment: не знаю кто тебе поставил лайк, но это пример как не надо задавать вопросы

Comment: Что в build.gradle?

Comment: Всё, добавил код

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно попробовать проверить следующие варианты:

1. Посмотреть какой server.port указанн в application.properties, возможно там не 8080.
2. Пересобрать проект(ввести команду gradle build), возможно index.html не добавился в сборку.
3. Попробовать убрать библиотеку **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf**, и тогда index.html по умолчанию из папки static вернется на get запрос http://localhost:port/
4. Если добавлена библиотека **spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf** то можно перенести файл index.html в папку **templates**
   И добавить класс

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

}
```